# type I error simulation in R

Tags: r, simulation, montecarlo

i am trying to calculate the type i error rate  and power for the correlation test for bivariate normal data using Monte Carlo simulation.

But i am getting unexpected values for the type I error and for power. (type I error as 0.864)

i need to know whether i have done some mistake. Can anyone help me?

```
set.seed(160230)
library("mvtnorm", lib.loc="~/R/win-library/3.4")
sigma= matrix(c(1,0.8,0.8,1),2,2) 
mu <- c(0,0)
#bivariate normal data
sim=replicate(n=1000 , rmvnorm(10,mean=mu , sigma = sigma))

pval1=c()

for(i in 1:1000)
{
 pval1[i]=cor.test(sim[,1,i],sim[,2,i],method = c("pearson"))$p.value

  }
#type1 error rate
mean(pval1<0.05)

#power
mean(pval3>0.05)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is okay but you have set up your simulations wrong.

In your code, you

1. Simulate bivariate data with a strong correlation, rho=0.8.
2. Test the hypothesis that H0: rho=0.

Thus, you are simulating data under the alternative hypothesis which is why you get the result of 0.864. This is essentially your power for that particular alternative. You could do the following instead:

First simulate data under the null hypothesis

```
sigma <- matrix(c(1,0,0,1),2,2) 
mu <- c(0,0)
#bivariate normal data under H0
sim <- replicate(n=1000, rmvnorm(10, mean=mu, sigma = sigma))

# Test the actual level under H0

result <- sapply(1:1000, function(i) { 
    cor.test(sim[,1,i],sim[,2,i],method = c("pearson"))$p.value})

mean(result < 0.05)
```

which gives a value around 0.05. Under the alternative you can use your code with the correlation 0.8 (or some other number). You can generalise this with the following code to easily get the power for several correlations.

```
rho <- seq(0, .9, .1)
pwr <- sapply(rho, function(r) {
    sigma <- matrix(c(1,r,r,1),2,2) 
    mu <- c(0,0)
    #bivariate normal data 
    sim <- replicate(n=1000, rmvnorm(10, mean=mu, sigma = sigma))

    # Test the actual level
    result <- sapply(1:1000, function(i) { 
        cor.test(sim[,1,i],sim[,2,i],method = c("pearson"))$p.value})

    mean(result < 0.05)
})
```

Then you can see the impact of correlation on the power byt plotting the relationship

```
plot(rho, pwr, type="l", xlab=expression(rho), ylab="Power")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi is the code for power calculation  `mean(result < 0.05)` is correct ?

Comment: Yup. It essentially counts the number of cases where the simulated p value is below 0.05 and divides by the number of simulations.

Comment: Hi But the Type 1 error rate also calculated by same code `mean(result < 0.05)` . So is it possible to have same value for both ?

Comment: Yes. It should be the same. It depends on whether you simulated data from under the null hypothesis (will give you the actual type I level) or from somewhere under the alternative hypothesis.